# Choose which field based on IFNULL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which I am trying to run in MySQL. Basically I am trying to work out how to update the corresponding field which *isn't* null. I know its going to be one of two possible fields but I want to update the one which isn't empty. Maybe I am missing something blindingly obvious, but this is what I've tried thus far:

```
UPDATE `table`
#SET IF(FieldA IS NULL,FieldB,FieldA) = 1234
#SET IFNULL(FieldA,FieldB) = 1234
WHERE `FieldC` = '5678'
AND   (
    `FieldA` = '1234'
    OR `FieldB` = '1234'
)
```

I suspect there may be a `CASE` solution but I'd prefer a shorthand/simple version option if it exists.

Comment: `COALESCE`?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(My)SQL has no syntax that allows you to dynamically change the column you want to update, e.g. something like `update ... set {PickFieldBaseOnCondition:FieldA|FieldB} = 1234`. You have to specify a column there. The moment you start your query, the basic structure of the query (and all fields involved) have to be clear and fixed, only the values can change.

So you need to update both fields in your query if it shall be able to modify two different columns. But you can of course decide to just not modify the content of a field based on its content, e.g. keep it if it is null already:

```
update `table` 
set FieldA = IF(FieldA IS NOT null, 1234, FieldA),
    FieldB = IF(FieldB IS NOT null, 1234, FieldB)
where ...
```

Note that the requirement "update the *other* field if a field is null" only works if your initial condition that one field is null and one is not null is fulfilled, which you said is given. Otherwise, you should include a test if both fields are null or both fields are not null (in the comparison for the first field), which you could e.g. do with

```
update `table` 
set FieldA = IF(FieldB IS null, 1234, null),
    FieldB = IF(FieldB IS NOT null, 1234, FieldB)
where ...
```

FieldA can now be changed from content to null if both fields are not null (and from null to content if both fields are null), to enforce the condition that exactly one field is not null.

Please also note that [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) is a MySQL-only shorthand for [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) and doesn't work in all databases. You prefered a non-case solution, but it can trivially be rewritten using the sql-standard `CASE`.

Comment: Very close and yes the figures were dummy. It should be (and I believe my query does this) - the opposite of this ... "e.g. if FieldA is not null, then replace it by its current value (so don't actually change it)".  So if Field A is not null, then update it with a value else leave it as null. So I guess its `coalesce` but in reverse.

Comment: @Antony lol, sorry, I misread which field should be updated. Fixed it. Doesn't really change the basic solution, just the comparion/function.

Comment: Why didn't I think of putting the check on the value side! Great answer.